# JavaScript regular expression returns false, but regex tester returning true

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a JavaScript regular expression that I'm using for frontend password validation in an input field. Here is what my input field looks like:

```
<input type='password' placeholder='Password...' id='password' pattern='^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})' required>
```

That regular expression is looking for a string: eight characters or longer, with an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number, and a special character. Let's take the string: November2017! for instance. That should pass the regular expression, but it doesn't in my webapp. And when I copy and paste the regular expression from my input field `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})` and put it into regex101.com, that string passes the validation. But it does not pass the validation in my webapp. Is there a specific reason why putting it in a `pattern` attribute would change whether or not it would pass validation?

Comment: Regex isn't 100% standardized, are you sure the regex tester was set to JavaScript's regex?

Comment: @Gry- yes, I checked it on the JavaScript regex

Comment: `pattern` requires to match the complete string. Your pattern does not match the complete string https://regex101.com/r/WcqXSR/1 It matches the position in the beginning of the string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `.{8,}` in the end.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}
```

It happens because the `pattern` must match the complete string, and your current expression only matches the beginning of the string.